# SSIS package , error de conexion a BD de Sql Server via puerto 3306

Tags: sql-server, ssis

He creado un paquete dtsx de SSIS que se conecta a una BD SqlServer remota y ejecuta en ella un procedimiento almacenado existente en la BD .

La red remota esta configurada de manera que la conexion a la BD se pueda realizar indistintamente por los puertos 1435 y 3306.

Ninguna de las dos cadenas de conexion a la BD remota da problemas si la conexion se ejecuta desde mi PC ya sea mediante el Management Studio o desde una aplicacion de escritorio de windows. En cambio, la ejecución del paquete dtsx sólo funciona si el puerto utilizado en la cadena de conexion es el 1435.

¿Sabeis si existe alguna configuracion de seguridad a nivel de SSIS que sea la causa de este comportamiento?

Comment: una disculpa de antemano ya que no es para aportacion si no para preguntar, ya que me encuentro con la necesidad de pasar la informacion de una base de datos local a una base de datos remoto esto es posible con ssis ?